# libgit2sharp is breaking my ability to open a solution

Tags: visual-studio, libgit2sharp

I'm honestly not even sure when I installed `libgit2sharp`, but, when I open *any* solution, Visual Studio 2015 crashes. The following errors are logged to the event viewer:

> Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 14.0.25123.0, time stamp: 0x56f22f32 Faulting module name: git2-msvstfs.DLL, version: 14.0.25110.0, time stamp: 0x56e1f02b Exception code: 0xc0000005 Fault offset: 0x00033710 Faulting process id: 0xfbc Faulting application start time: 0x01d1b5d840a79b09 Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\git2-msvstfs.DLL Report Id: e7833424-fc8b-4d26-b61b-c824861a3168
>   Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

**and**

> Application: devenv.exe
>   Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
>      at LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods.git_status_list_new(LibGit2Sharp.Core.Handles.StatusListSafeHandle ByRef, LibGit2Sharp.Core.Handles.RepositorySafeHandle, LibGit2Sharp.Core.GitStatusOptions)
>      at LibGit2Sharp.RepositoryStatusWithDetails..ctor(LibGit2Sharp.Repository, LibGit2Sharp.StatusOptions)
>      at LibGit2Sharp.RepositoryExtensions.RetrieveStatusWithDetails(LibGit2Sharp.IRepository, LibGit2Sharp.StatusOptions)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.CoreServices.Extensions.GitExtensions.RetrieveStatusWithDetailsWithRenameDetection(LibGit2Sharp.IRepository)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.CoreServices.SccStatusService+RepositoryStatusMonitor+<>c__DisplayClass18_1.b__0()
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.CoreServices.SccStatusService+RepositoryStatusMonitor.RetryLoop(System.Action, Int32)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.CoreServices.SccStatusService+RepositoryStatusMonitor.Refresh(Boolean ByRef, Boolean ByRef)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.CoreServices.SccStatusService+RepositoryStatusMonitor.RefreshIfNeeded(Boolean ByRef, Boolean ByRef)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.CoreServices.SccStatusService.Refresh(Boolean ByRef, Boolean ByRef, Boolean ByRef, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 ByRef)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.CoreServices.SccStatusService.RefreshIfNeeded()
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.CoreServices.SccStatusService.QueuedActionCallback(System.Object)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.CoreServices.QueuedActionLimiter.DeliverAction(System.Object)
>      at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
>      at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()

I've never seen this before so any direction is appreciated:

- What mechanism is breaking - why is RetrieveStatusWithDetails even being called?
- How do I investigate the root cause and correct this?
- Have I found a defect in `libgit2sharp`?

Comment: This is Team Explorer trying to display the Changes page for your Git repository.  It looks like this is VS 2015 Update 2?  Has this _ever_ worked or did it just start happening?

Comment: It only recently started. Set this machine up on Thursday of last week, the issue popped up today.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm honestly not even sure when I installed libgit2sharp

You didn't; it is included as part of Visual Studio and is the mechanism used for managing your Git repository.

> What mechanism is breaking - why is RetrieveStatusWithDetails even being called?

This is Team Explorer trying to show the status of your Git repository.

> How do I investigate the root cause and correct this?

It is unlikely that you can.

> Have I found a defect in libgit2sharp?

You've found a defect in Visual Studio and you should report it to Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

I had this today.  Didn't find any specific help, but did managed to completely turn off GIT support in Visual Studio 2013 which stopped me experiencing the problem.

Tools->Options->Source Control.  And remove GIT Support from the list.